# What is the prob. distribution of the sum of RVs if nothing is known about its individual distributions neither about their independence??

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, stochastic-analysis

For the distribution of the sum of random variables... It is possible to made a "worst case distribution" function if there is no information about the random variables been added??? this meaning don't knowing if they are dependent or independent, neither if their dependence is slightly or strong, and also not knowing nothing about if they have all different probability distributions or not, or just maybe a few ones RVs share the same distribution and the others not. . .
and also: This "worst case distribution" will be in inside the "stable distributions" family or not?

Comment: What *do* we know about the individual random variables?

Comment: Nothing more than that they are random variables.... I want to know if there exist something similar to the "law of big numbers" for any kind of possible RVs sumation... thinking about the "concentration laws for RVs" that gives upper bounds for the tails of their distributions, I believe that something must exist for this widespread case.

Comment: If you know nothing at all about the individual random variables, then you know nothing at all about their sum.

Comment: Even the law of large numbers requires knowing something, e.g. that the random variables have a finite first moment.

Comment: You cannot say anything about the sum in general, for example, if X is a random variable, then -X is also a random variable and we have X+ (-X) = 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't even know something about a single RV, it's impossible to know any more about what happens when you add multiple RVs together.

A random variable could:

- Be discrete or continuous
- Have finite or infinite support
- Have finite or undefined mean
- Have finite or infinite variance
- Be well-behaved or pathological in some fashion

A pair of random variables could be:

- Independent
- Perfectly correlated
- Perfectly anti-correlated
- Related by a non-linear function
- Defined on completely incompatible sets

As such, the sum of them could be:

- Easy to calculate
- Hard to calculate
- Impossible to calculate
- Not a meaningful quantity

Add more RVs into the equation, and all of those possibilities remain. I may as well tell you "I'm thinking of five numbers and a breed of cat. What do you think their sum is?".